# No module named tkinter when using tkintertables

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When trying to import tkintertable (which is dependent upon Pmw), I am getting the error -- "no module named tkinter".  I understand this is a compatibility issue between Python 2.0 and 3.0, but I cannot figure out where I should change tkinter to Tkinter.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reading the traceback?

Comment: Just before your code use successive imports: `import Tkinter as tkinter`.

Comment: Then you can use your other imports that depend on `tkinter` not `Tkinter`.

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing still happens after importing Tkinter as tkinter

Comment: Without seeing exactly inside the module `Pmw` or `tkintertable` is difficult to help... maybe you could provide a description of the version of the modules that you installed...

Comment: what version of Python are you using?  tkintertable does not support Python 3x.  According to [docs at pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkintertable), '...This is Python 2 only.'