# what kind of table widget module i should use for python 3x

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to use `tkintertable` for Python 3.5.2 but I got an error message at the console saying:

```
File "C:\Users\issba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\tkintertable\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from Tables import *
ImportError: No module named 'Tables'
```

Then I found out it's out of date using one of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650901/no-module-named-tkinter-when-using-tkintertables). So I looked on Google yesterday till I got `tktable` but I could not find the supported releases, so my question is: 
Is it true that `tkintertable` is no longer available for Python 3x and what is a replacement for this issue? Please try to provide a link for setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable) is the official development site of `tkintertable`. At the end of the [about section](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable#about) it says:

> **This library is currently for Python 2 only.**

I think it clears the question on whether it is available for Python 3 or not.

And for your second question:

> what is a replacement for this issue?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456445/how-to-imitate-this-table-using-tkinter) can be useful.

Comment: thank you sir i found this one i looked for the first time for a tutorial it was showing wrong tree of maximizing and minimizing option only now i found another tutorial